# No implementation of method for class: clojure.lang.ArraySeq

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I wrote a Clojure function that uses recur to process through a list and returns the results back in a vector...

```
(defn do_stuff [input, results]
 ;; using recur and conj here to build up results
)
```

I have a another function where I need to pass the result of do_stuff, and I get this error:

> No implementation of method: :to_my_format of protocol:     #'com.beebunny.to_my_format found for class: clojure.lang.ArraySeq

My to_my_format function has an implementation for clojure.lang.IPersistentVector and IPersistentList. Is there a way I can convert to one or the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix is to wrap the `ArraySeq` with `into`.

```
(into [] array-seq)
```

But it might be better if you refactor the protocol to work with `ISeq` if all you need is to sequentially scan through the data and produce result. As such, anything that is *sequential* can be passed in with a simple `seq` call.

Comment: Can you post more code? Especially how you get that ArraySeq and how you transformed it.